# Automating PPP connection: adding the insertion in routing table of the new interface

Tags: networking, ppp

I start my USB **3G Modem** by:

```
# wvdial
```

And then I must do, in order to acquire **internet** access:

```
# route add default ppp0
```

Note that `ppp0` is, in this case, the newly created virtual network interface.
I would like to **automate** this:

```
#!/bin/bash 
wvdial
route add default ppp0
```

But sometimes there is some previous ppp connection established (i.e: VPN), so the correct adapter must have another number (it is created as `ppp1`, `ppp2`... etc), and I need to parse `ifconfig` output or any other method.

Isn't there a more practical way to **automate the routing** part of the PPP connection?

EDIT-1: This is my `/etc/wvdial.conf` :

```
[Dialer Defaults]
Init1 = ATZ
Init2 = ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0
Init3 = AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","ac.vodafone.es";
Modem = /dev/ttyUSB0
Phone = *99***1#
Username = vodafone
Password = vodafone
Stupid Mode = 1
# Carrier Check = no
#Dial Command = ATDT
#Baud = 9600
Baud = 460800
ISDN = 0
Modem Type = Analog Modem
```

The carrier is Vodafone.

EDIT-2: My distro is Kali Linux v1.0.5

EDIT-3: Added to `/etc/wvdial.conf` :

```
New PPPD = yes
```

Still no results :-( .

Comment: Did you check, whether *Check Def Route* is set to yes in your */etc/wvdial.conf* ?

Comment: Negative, @SeDav. My `/etc/wvdial.conf` has no reference to `Check Def Route`. I have edited original post to add it.

Comment: Normally accordng to [the man page](http://linux.die.net/man/5/wvdial.conf) it should be activated by default, if there is no entry, but could you try to add *Check Def Route = yes* This should tell wvdial to add the default route automatically.

Comment: Tested, but not working, @SeDav. Results are the same. My distro is Kali Linux v1.0.5.

Comment: @SeDav , `Check Def Route` is reported by the man page as «Option added by SuSE». Is this supposed to mean that any other distro will not work with it?

Comment: It is meant to be present in all distros. In one of the github forks I found it in the code. But it seems to check only, not set. Maybe you can post your logs,
`if( do_check_dfr )
{
if( check_dfr() )
log( "Default route Ok.\n" );
else
log( "Default route failure.\n" );
}}`
One of the above messages should appear.

Comment: @SeDav , I get some `Syntax error on unexpected (`. I ran it by using sudo. I think I could try to correct your code, but I prefer for you to do it, to not change your intended sense.

Comment: I'm Sorry. I could have made it clearer. The code I posted was taken out of the sources of wvdial at https://github.com/wlach/wvdial/blob/master/wvdialmon.cc It wasn't intended to be executed by you at all (it is C++ Code). But it tells me that some of the above message strings should appear. So by running your *wvdial* with the option `Check  Def Route = yes` in the config from the command line, there should be some kind of logging output. This could help to solve your question.

Comment: It is possible to create a custom script in ppp to work around this problem: https://superuser.com/questions/949520/wvdial-ppp0-and-setting-default-route-automatically

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, you should do:

```
route del default
```

You can test if the default route is deleted with the command:

```
route -n
```

Add the default route using the modem IP and gateway as default route. For example:

```
route add default netmask 0.0.0.0 gw {IP_GATEWAY_FROM_3G_MODEM} dev ppp0
```

You can test, everything is working fine with a simple traceroute command.

```
traceroute google.es
```

Comment: I think you did not understood the question at all.